# Liferay: Role that can add web content only in certain pages of the site

Tags: liferay-6

Is it posible to define a role which can only create/read/update/delete web content in certain pages of the site? For example the role "NewsContent" can only add web content to the news page (and it's subpages).

I couldn't achieve this so far since I don't see anything like this in when adding permissions to a role. I can set the "Add web content" permission to a role but with this permission the users with this role will be able to add web content in all the pages of the site.

I hope that this is posible since this feature is very important for my application.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Portlets in your application? If so, below solution which is for JSF based portlets can be of help.

As per my understanding "NewsContent" role can only add web content to the news page. So, I guess you have a Portlet which displays news page. In this case, get the role of the user from Liferay DB.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        javax.faces.context.ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
if(externalContext.isUserInRole("NewsContent"))
{
  //Allow this user to do what you want him to do
}
```

If you are not using JSF based Portlets, you can still make a query to Liferay DB and get the role of the user logged in by querying in `USER_`, `USERS_ROLES` and `ROLE_` tables.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Control-Panel=>Roles

Select particular role in which you assign the user
select define permission for that role
select site administration
Enable only Manage pages checkbox in site
Now user with that particular role is able to ad web content on a page.

This will resolve your issue.